# MVP, JFrame, JDialog : GUI is freezing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have main frame (with JFrame field) asi **view**, then **presenter** (created in view's constructor) that adds listeners to buttons and stuff. I do that like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

MyWindow invokes in it's constructor only one method - intialize - that only creates GUI fields. Finally (literally last line of it's code) it creates presenter.

Presenter should show new JDialog on certain events in main view. It has one method, **that makes my GUI freeze**. It looks like this:

```
protected double[] getParams(final Class<?> indicatorClass) {
        ParametrizableDialog dialog = dialogs.get(indicatorClass); // works well
        List<Double> params = new ArrayList<Double>();
        dialog.setParams(params);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(view.getFrame());
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(params); // it actually works, params are obtained from JDialog as user input
        return Doubles.toArray(params); // guava
    }
```

`ParametrizableDialog` is normal `JDialog` that implements one method interface that sets `List<Double`> parameters like this:

```
public class ParametrizableDialog extends JDialog implements Parametrizable {

    protected List<Double> params;

    @Override
    public void setParams(final List<Double> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

}
```

Now, does anybody know what mistake did I make and why does my GUI freeze? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the GUI _freezes_?

Comment: That you can't interact with UI components, it hangs ...

Comment: Does this only happen when the `JDialog` is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a GUI freezes, its generally because your are blocking the EDT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

We can't tell what you are doing because your code isn't complete. For example you don't even add any components to the GUI. So who knows what you are doing in the code you left out.

For more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I tried to write SSCCE and I did find out, that it was another problem (I failed to prove error). Thank you for pointing me right way.